# How do I replace the remote branch with the local branch in git?

Tags: git

I screwed up and merged in a branch that shouldn't have been merged in. I then pushed the changes before I realized what I'd done. This changed about 30k files (it was a new version of a third party app).

I have reset my local branch to before the merge, but when I push to the remote, it just pulls the bad merge back in.

How do I tell git that I want my local branch to replace the remote tracking branch when I push?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "when I push to the remote, it just pulls the bad merge back in"? How are you pushing? Exactly what commands are you running, and what is their output? Does the remote repo allow force pushing?

Comment: I am pushing from my IDE, which shows me that the remote is now ahead of my local, and thinking about it, it's probably the IDE that pulls the bad merge back in. I will try doing a push from the command line to see what happens.

Comment: The push fails because `the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart`. I will look into force pushing, but really I want to remove the merge from the remote branch, which I thought was going to happen when I pushed the local having removed the merge from local

Comment: If the remote is ahead, then a push won't work by default, you'll have to force-push. But since you're only vaguely describing what's happening, it's hard to tell for sure.